# VB6 Crystal Reports 8.5.0.217 - Access Violation Application Crash

Tags: windows-7, vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

**Background:**

Our company uses Crystal Reports in our legacy product written in VB6 which I'm performing some maintenance duties for.

Its using version 8.5.0.217 [RTM] with no service packs.

---

**The Problem:**

Has worked perfectly on Windows XP x86 to date.

In Windows 7 [x86 and x64] we get an Access Violation followed by an application crash and no further usable error information.

---

**The Details:**

The application crashes with a large datasets for any report using the active x viewer.
Visual Studio will crash whilst debugging.

The offending code is here:

```
Crv_Obj(0).ReportSource = ReportParametersFrm.Report
Crv_Obj(0).EnablePopupMenu = True
Crv_Obj(0).ViewReport
```

I have checked that:

- `Crv_Obj(0)` is a valid object reference.
- `ReportParametersFrm.Report` is a valid reference.

The only information I have is from the event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: Pyramid.exe, version: 2.2.0.8, time stamp: 0x51e53053
Faulting module name: craxdrt.dll, version: 8.5.0.217, time stamp: 0x3a849e1a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002ac3d1
Faulting process id: 0x15a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce8228a295c8c8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Pyramid\Pyramid.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Pyramid\CrystalSys\craxdrt.dll
```

I have also tried:

- Disabling the DEP to no effect.
- Changing Compatibility to Windows XP and below.
- Running as both privileged and nonprivileged users.
- Tried adding in new error handlers to catch the error
- [Fruitlessly] searching on Google and this site.
- Contacting SAP [to then be ignored].

---

**What I need help with:**

- Have you seen this before?
- Are there any workarounds or something I should be looking for that is obviously wrong?
- Is there more recent version of Crystal that supports VB6 or at least
  an upgrade path that you know of that I can attempt?

Any and all help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a lot of research and digging around it seems that a slightly newer version of craxdrt.dll crviewer.dll fixes the problem.

Simply a case of replacing these libraries in the application lib folder and in C:\Windows\System32\

I've put a copy of the libs [here](http://www.grey-area.info/uploads/Crystal-8.5.0.674.zip) in the event anyone else has this problem as there was very little consistent help/information out there on the internet.